# Why TensorFlow throws this exception when loading a model that was normalized like this?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

All latest versions from the very moment of this post.

```
tensorflow-gpu: 2.6.0
Python: 3.9.7
CUDA: 11.4.2
cuDNN: 8.2.4
```

As in the code below, when loading a model that was normalized by not passing arguments to `Normalization()` it throws an exception when that model is loaded by `load_model()`, however before loading the model I can use it without any apparent issues which makes you think it's all good since `Normalization()` did NOT complain and took care of the input shape. When loading a model that was normalized by `Normalization(input_dim=5)` it does NOT thrown any exception since a known shape is specified. That is weird I mean **it should warn you that when normalizing it without passing arguments to `Normalization()` you should expect an exception when loading it**.

I'm not sure if it's a bug so I'm posting it here before reporting a bug in the github section, maybe I'm missing to setup something.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def main():
    train_data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
    train_label = np.array([123])
    
    # Uncomment this to load the model and comment the next model and normalizer related lines.
    #model = tf.keras.models.load_model('AI/test.h5')

    normalizer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
    normalizer.adapt(train_data)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([normalizer, tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1), loss='mean_absolute_error')
    model.fit(train_data, train_label, epochs=3000)

    model.save('AI/test.h5')

    unseen_data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]])

    prediction = model.predict(unseen_data)
    print(prediction)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Backup\Desktop\tensorflow_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Backup\Desktop\tensorflow_test.py", line 11, in main
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('AI/test.h5')
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py", line 200, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects,
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 180, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 52, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 208, in deserialize
    return generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object(
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 674, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 434, in from_config
    model.add(layer)
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 530, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 217, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 976, in __call__
    return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1114, in _functional_construction_call
    outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 848, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 886, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2659, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\normalization.py", line 145, in build
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: All `axis` values to be kept must have known shape. Got axis: (-1,), input shape: [None, None], with unknown axis at index: 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug.
[Follow this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0bfc9ef7eef571af0cc41127673d3c67783121f4/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L426)

> ```
> if 'input_dim' in kwargs and 'input_shape' not in kwargs:
>   # Backwards compatibility: alias 'input_dim' to 'input_shape'.
>   kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs['input_dim'],)
> if 'input_shape' in kwargs or 'batch_input_shape' in kwargs:
>   # In this case we will later create an input layer
>   # to insert before the current layer
>   if 'batch_input_shape' in kwargs:
>     batch_input_shape = tuple(kwargs['batch_input_shape'])
>   elif 'input_shape' in kwargs:
>     if 'batch_size' in kwargs:
>       batch_size = kwargs['batch_size']
>     else:
>       batch_size = None
>     batch_input_shape = (batch_size,) + tuple(kwargs['input_shape'])
>   self._batch_input_shape = batch_input_shape
> ```

The error occurs because the normalization could not get any shape information which would lead to `self._input_batch_shape =(None, None)`.

But when loading model(deserialization), It would call [`build`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3a33d53ea4aca312c5ad650b4883d9bac608a32e/keras/layers/preprocessing/normalization.py#L144) function which should have known shape in all axes.

> ```
> # Sorted to avoid transposing axes.
> self._keep_axis = sorted([d if d >= 0 else d + ndim for d in self.axis])
> # All axes to be kept should have known shape.
> for d in self._keep_axis:
>   if input_shape[d] is None:
>     raise ValueError(
>         'All `axis` values to be kept must have known shape. Got axis: {}, '
>         'input shape: {}, with unknown axis at index: {}'.format(
>             self.axis, input_shape, d))
> ```

Comment: Yeah, I'm reporting this at the github section as a possible bug, thanks for showing me that.